# How can others connect to my consul data in their machine using my Ip address

Tags: consul

I am working in spring microservice project and I am using consul for centralized configuration and service discovery. I am running consul in my local machine and I want it to be available for also others if they hit URL using my IP address.
How to achieve this?

*consul agent -server -bootstrap-expect=1 -data-dir=hoppy -ui -bind=**<IP Address>***

This is the command I am giving in command prompt for running consul and I check COnsul in my browser using **localhost:8500/ui** or **127.0.0.1:8500**. But if I try to use **<IP Address>:8500**, it's not working. I have asked another people to check in their machine using **<IP Address>:8500**, in this I given my IP to them. But it's not working.

How they can connect to my consul with my IP address?

Comment: *Other users* on the same host, same LAN, or *anywhere on the internet*?

Comment: yeah other user should able to connect to the  database which I stored in my consul. I have stored a configuration file in my consul. If they use my ip address in their laptop using my system IP address they should be able to access the same configuration file over internet

Comment: *their laptop* seems to imply *not the same host*. If *not the same LAN(/WAN)*, you need to concern yourself with *firewalls*.